# Clarify docker-tag and docker-push command

Tags: docker

I have seen usage of `docker tag ...` and `docker push ...` after building an image. When using local registry, people usually include the registry host address in both commands. Is that actually necessary?

---

More details and my thoughts

From `man docker-tag`:

> `docker tag [-f|--force[=false]] [--help] IMAGE[:TAG] [REGISTRY_HOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]`

1. Why we want to provide `REGISTRY_HOST` when tagging?

   As I understand, when doing tagging the docker daemon does not communicate with the registry. So I guess the whole `[REGISTRY_HOST/]USERNAME/]NAME` is a naming suggestion, which will be interpreted as a single `REPOSITORY` string when we are doing `docker ps`.

From `man docker-push`:

> `docker push [--help] NAME[:TAG] | [REGISTRY_HOST[:REGISTRY_PORT]/]NAME[:TAG]`

2. If we have already tagged an image with registry host and username etc., why do we need to provide them in `push`?

   Since push does communicate with the registry, I think the `REGISTRY_HOST[:REGISTRY_PORT]/]` are actually parsed, and the `NAME` might refer to the `[USERNAME/]NAME` in the tag command. The `[REGISTRY_HOST/]` in `tag` is ignored here.

I am completely guessing about how `tag` and `push` work. Please point out if I am wrong and explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I do not missunderstand your questions.

1. Docker TAG - you can tag your image as you like. Following the rules of naming conventions and good practice, you should tag it with you repository. In case you are trying to push an image to the official docker hub .. it **needs** to be tagged with your account name (simply to understand that the image is connected/mapped to your account)
2. I am a bit lost for this - you are simply pushing the image by using the previously given tag ("name" if you want). In case you want to push your image in two different locations you need to tell docker where to push them - by using the registry host information. So for example you can use `docker push youraccount/yourimage` if you already are logged into dockerhub. In case you want to push to gitlab as your docker image repository for example, they asked you to use - `docker push my-registry:5000/my-image`

I think the actual guide from docker has reasonable examples - https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/

Answer (score 0):

1. Tagging is just adding another name to the image. You can give an image as many tags as you like, or you can give it the name with the registry location when you build it so it only ever has one tag. Each tag points to the image via a checksum and has no direct knowledge of any other tags for that same image.
2. Pushing an image depends on the tag to know where to push it. The push command looks at the section before the first slash for "localhost", a "." for the domain/ip, or a ":" for the port, and if it finds any of those, it will push to that host. If it finds none of them, it will by default push with that name to the Docker Hub where they require that you include your username as the first part of your image. If you push an image without the registry hostname, it knows nothing about the other tags you may have created for the image, in fact you could have multiple tags out there for multiple registry servers, so it only pushes to the one on the command line you give it.